# How to hide a div while keeping the other divs below the same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a smooth scroll down animation like [this](https://wearebarbarian.com/). [Here](https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/GBRmgx) is my animation.

My problem is that the animation works fine on Chrome, but on Safari and Firefox, the animation makes the user scroll to the bottom of the page not the begin of it.

My code for creating the animation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#index"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

   // This function makes the scroll animation to the div with the id="index"
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 100
    }, 1200);

    //Once the user clicks on the button and scrolls to the div. The two divs above the index div are hidden after 1300 millsecs.
    $('.introsection').delay(1300).hide(0);
    $('#swipe-down').delay(1300).hide(0);
    $('#home').css('margin-top', '0');
});
```

Why does code below works fine on Chrome, but on Firefox/Safari doesn't work as similar as Chrome?

```
$('.introsection').delay(1300).hide(0);$('#swipe-down').delay(1300).hide(0);
```

Comment: why that `-100` in `scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 100`...if you remove it, it will work in FF and safari

Comment: @AravindS Yeah, I tried that. It does not work. I added the -100 because I wanted to add a navbar after.

Comment: i guess the issue is there only with animate, if i change to this `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 485}, 2000);` means it working. could you please try once?

Comment: @AravindS Still does not work could you link me your codepen, please?

Comment: here https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/vaLqzp

Comment: in btw in your ref site, they are handling it through minheight only

Comment: @AravindS interesting but it doesn't scroll pass the blue box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176161/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-jafar-salami).